# Error handling: Exceptions vs Error method

Tags: c#, oop, error-handling, 3-tier

I'm creating a 3-tier app and I have a problem dealing with error handling. I don't know if I should throw an exception or call a method to communicate the problem to the other layers.

Here is a quick exemple, I have:
 - a `FileChooserFrame` (Presentation tier) that allow the user to select a file in a list.
 - a `DataHandler`(App tier) that do some stuff with the path of the file and do the link between Presentation & Data tier.
 - a `FileParser` (Data tier) that parse the file and get data from it.

Now let say that the file must follow a special  structure, and if it's not, I want to show a MessageBox.
I'm not able to know if the user selected a good file before parsing it.

My question is, what do I do when I see that the file isn't following the structure ?
I thought about 2 things:
1 - Stop the current action and call a method in `DataHandler` (ex. `NotifyWrongFileErr()`) that'll ask the frame to show the messageBox.
2 - Throw a custom exception that I catch in the `FileChooserFrame` that'll show the pop-up.

Both of the case have their pros/cons so I can't choose between them. What would be the most appropriate thing to do ?

PS: In case n°2, where do I write the Exception class ? In a file dedicated to the app's Exceptions, or next to the class that'll throw it ?

Comment: look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's your choice, the best practise with exceptions is to generally only throw exceptions under circumstances that you didn't expect.  Since you are expecting a person to be able to select an invalid file name, then calling the method may be considered "best practise".  But again, there is no right or wrong and do what you like as long as you are happy with it.  If it was me I would create a set of Data Tier exceptions for things like this and throw them, that way if I ever wanted to test the data teir using some test code (IoC) I would see exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If it is "expected", that user can have invalid input, and there is standard response for that, in that case there is no need for exception. It is a part of the data processing. Just make sure to perform all necessary cleanups when the validation fails.

Answer (score 1):

What about an event handling system?

The exception handling requires a try/catch/throw structure that "bubbles" event wherever you want in an expensive way. 
But, if you fire an event from the FileParser handled in DataHandler (or Bubbled on top to the presentation tier) you are able to decouple every module from the others.

A little example (assuming DataHandler tier "knows" FileParser tier):

```
class FileParser
{
public event EventHandler ParsingFailedEvent;

public void ParseFile()
{
// 1. Parse the file
// 2. File structure isn't correct, raise event!

            ParsingFailedEvent.Invoke(sender, e);
}

}

class DataHandler
{
private FileParser fp = new FileParser();
public DataHandler()
{

            fp.ParsingFailedEvent+= new EventHandler(this.FileParsingHandler);
}

public void FileParsingHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// do something, maybe display a MessageBox
}

}
```

This shows you how different are Exceptions from Events, mostly due to Error/Fault related condition of the first one.
On the other side you have methods, but I think events are more flexible due to their delegate system or dynamic binding facility.

In my opinion, avoid custom exception for logic, nobody knows when you put an Exception in your code and nobody knows when it will translate in some Application failure.

Take a look to WPF way to handle and route events, it will help you [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753115.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generation of exception more expensive from the viewpoint of performance than ask the frame to show the messageBox